# Possible to have editor window tabs dynamically resize to fit into view

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just to clarify, this question has nothing to do with tabs inside a document.  This is about editor tabs (like browser tabs) in Visual Studio Code.  When I have more open than the window will show the extras disappear from view.  Is there a way to have them automatically resized so they all fit into view the way a web browser would do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should do it:

```
// Controls the sizing of editor tabs.

//  - `fit`: Always keep tabs large enough to show the full editor label.   
//  - `shrink`: Allow tabs to get smaller when the available space is not enough to show all tabs
 at once.

"workbench.editor.tabSizing": "shrink",
```

Comment: How does this get a downvote?  Sigh, but see this later duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/52822390/836330 ??