# Visual Studio Code tab width

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to set the maximum width for the tab in visual studio code. I can specify this in visual studio 2015 when I install productivity power tool, but I want to know if this is possible with visual studio code.
[image]

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The only thing I was able to find while doing some quick research on [VS Code User Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) was that in the Settings editor you can change the tabWidth either to shrink or to stay large enough to view the file name.

```
  // Controls the sizing of editor tabs.
  //  - fit: Always keep tabs large enough to show the full editor label.
  //  - shrink: Allow tabs to get smaller when the available space is not enough to show all tabs at once.
  "workbench.editor.tabSizing": "fit",
```

Comment: If `shrink`  is used, it will also remove the `X` (which is a good thing). It reappears on mouse hover, but anyway you can close a tab with middle-click.

Comment: There is also `pinnedTabSizing`! I didn't know this old functionality was still accessible.

Answer (score 11):

In VS Code you can access the editor's tab size settings by pressing `Command+Comma` (Mac) or `Ctrl+Comma` (PC), and typing `tabsizing`. You can edit settings for regular and pinned tabs.

Currently there are two options for sizing editor tabs: `fit` and `shrink`.

[image: Dialog to edit tab sizing in VS Code]

A handy shortcut is that the tab area recognizes a mouse scroll-wheel.

If you have `Tab Sizing` set to `fit`, and you have several tabs opened so that they scroll off the screen, hover your mouse pointer over a tab then scroll. This will bring more tabs into view.

<s>It would be nice if Microsoft provided a means to stack tabs in Visual Studio Code.</s>

**2022 Update:** VS Code now has a workbench setting named `Wrap Tabs`. To edit this press `Command+Comma` (Mac) or `Ctrl+Comma` (PC), type `Wrap Tabs` and check that box.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

VSCode 1.79 (May 2023) offers another alternative option: fixed width tabs.

> ### [New tab sizing option fixed](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_new-tab-sizing-option-fixed)
>
> The `workbench.editor.tabSizing` setting has a new option `fixed` that makes each tab equal width.
> When space becomes limited, tabs will shrink equally up to a minimum.
>
> The new setting `workbench.editor.tabSizingFixedMaxWidth` sets the initial size of the tab.

(So that is one "way to set the maximum width for the tab in Visual Studio Code")

> In this mode, when you rapidly close tabs using the mouse, the widths of tabs remain stable to allow for closing each tab by clicking onto the same point.
> The width is then adjusted when you leave the mouse from the editor tab area.
>
> [image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_79/tab-size-fixed.mp4]

---

As [dannypernik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3295556/dannypernik) mention in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822269/visual-studio-code-tab-width/76452038?noredirect=1#comment135916593_76452038):

> I'd love to use fixed tabSizing and wrapTabs together
>
> If `workbench.editor.tabSizingFixedMinWidth` (minimum width) is set and `wrapTabs` is true, tabs will wrap when the first row is full.

Comment: This is great, and I will probably use it given the current options. However, I'd love to use fixed tabSizing and wrapTabs together. It seems that fixed tabSizing disables wrapTabs.

Comment: @dannypernik True. That seems like a bug, or at least some unwanted side effect.

Comment: I take that back – I reviewed related Github issues and learned of the `workbench.editor.tabSizingFixedMinWidth` setting. If minimum width is set and `wrapTabs` is true, tabs will wrap when the first row is full. Huzzah!

Comment: @dannypernik Good catch, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

As lenooh pointed out, to have smaller tabs (what I came here for), better use
`"workbench.editor.tabSizing": "shrink",`