# How to change tab width of open widows

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I change tab width in vs code? (not indentation width of tab/space)
Many results are about indentation but I couldn't find one for width of those tabs
As filenames are pretty long and I can have 5-6 currently open, I'd like to resize them somehow on max width so I can read component name without .component.ts/html part and have many more visible

Is this possible to set in settings or I need to do some custom coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab width can be set as [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) post explains, you are looking for

> "workbench.editor.tabSizing"

but it doesn't seem like you are abel to edit the name.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822269/visual-studio-code-tab-width) post might help

Comment: "workbench.editor.tabSizing" : "shrink" was exactly what I was looking for