# VSCode settings for file Title

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I accommodate all the file Names/Titles in Top bar in VSCode ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to have editor window tabs dynamically resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52084313/possible-to-have-editor-window-tabs-dynamically-resize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```json
"workbench.editor.tabSizing": "shrink",
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex. It is working.  But is it possible to display tabs as 2 or 3 Layers/Rows ?

Comment: No. It's not possible.